# How can I get from all vertex on the left side minimum vertex cover on the right side?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, bipartite

Some company throws a party for a particular number of employees and to make a good party, the company has to buy different sorts of beers. Each employee has its favorite beer. The problem is to determine how much different sorts of beers a company has to buy in order not to offend employees.

**Input data:**

```
2 2
YN NY
```

**Output data:**

```
2
```

(the first row contains 2 numbers the first is number of employees and the second one is number of beers are available. The second row shows characters Y-yes (means employee like this sort of beer), N-no (means employee doesn't like this sort of beer))

**Input data:**

```
6 3
YNN YNY YNY NYY NYY NYN
```

**Output data:**

```
2
```

*(the most optimal will be to buy 1 and 3 sorts of beers)*

**Constraints**

```
0 < employees < 50 
0 < beers < 50
```

**My thoughts and assumption:**

we can imagine this problem in a bipartite graph so on the left side we have employees and on the right side we have sorts of beers. The relation between them is employee preference. 
**How we can find that minimum?**

[image]

**Which algorithm can solve this problem? 
Are there any different approaches?**

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: a possible way could be to represent each kind of beer by a boolean variable, express each employee's taste by (a+b) (if he likes beer a and b), and take the product of all employee's taste (AND). (idea being to use absorption). Then develop the expression and keep the lowest term's degree. But how many kind of beers, how many employees?

Comment: 0 < employees < 50

0 < beers < 50